# What is the purpose of the postmaster, webmaster, etc. email addresses?

Tags: email

I guess the following email address are frequently (if not always) used :
postmaster@domain, webmaster, abuse, services...

But what are their purposes ? Why create them ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so there are well-known contact addresses.

- `postmaster` is whoever operates the mail server.
- `webmaster` is whoever operates the web server.
- `abuse` is whoever handles what are likely violations of the Terms of Service (so these commonly exist on providers).

Generally, if I find some other mail server misbehaving (e.g. not accepting mail when it should), I contact the `postmaster`, and when I find a problem on a webserver (e.g. someone hosting a virus on a hacked machine) I contact the `webmaster`.

In general there is an expectation that if you find a problem, you notify people before it grows, and if you provide a service, you should be easy to contact.

We get very little spam on these well-known addresses, probably because spammers have learned that they generally connect to people who are able to track down spam to its source and forward it to the appropriate `abuse` address with a request to look into the matter, so that is an excellent way to get your operation shut down.

Comment: These and several others are defined in RFC 2142.